# Is there a way to give a Java Document an XML schema for XPath queries

Tags: java, xpath, xsd

`javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder` can build a document from a single stream which is the XML file. However, I can't find any way to also give it a schema file.

Is there a way to do this so that my XPath queries can perform type aware queries and return typed data?

Comment: If you want to represent elements with appropriate types and validate documents, try JAXB. You can even generate the classes from an XML Schema document in a couple of seconds.

Comment: What do you mean type aware queries and typed data? I'm only superficially familiar with XPath so I don't know what those mean.

Comment: Shouldn't the schema be associated with a namespace and declared in the source XML document?

Comment: @SteveH. The declaration of a schema file is not necessarily the location of the schema file. It's a common practice but not a requirement.

Comment: @Tom I looked again but it appears that JAXB does not support XPath. Am I missing something?

Comment: @DavidThielen unfortunately, XPath is not supported by JAXB. It may not be necessary to use, though. The library creates navigable object graphs so you can do without XPath for simple queries. If you want to use XPath with JAXB, you can check out Apache Commons' [JXPath utility](http://commons.apache.org/jxpath/). It's said to allow XPath queries to object graphs. I haven't used it though.

Answer (score 1):

The JAXP API is designed for XPath 1.0 and has never been upgraded to handle 2.0 concepts like schema-aware queries. If you are using Saxon, use the s9api interface instead of JAXP.

Here's an example of schema aware XPath taken from s9apiExamples.java in the saxon-resources download:

```
/**
 * Demonstrate use of a schema-aware XPath expression
 */

private static class XPathC implements S9APIExamples.Test {
    public String name() {
        return "XPathC";
    }
    public boolean needsSaxonEE() {
        return true;
    }
    public void run() throws SaxonApiException {
    Processor proc = new Processor(true);

    SchemaManager sm = proc.getSchemaManager();
    sm.load(new StreamSource(new File("data/books.xsd")));
    SchemaValidator sv = sm.newSchemaValidator();
    sv.setLax(false);

    XPathCompiler xpath = proc.newXPathCompiler();
    xpath.declareNamespace("saxon", "http://saxon.sf.net/"); // not actually used, just for demonstration
    xpath.importSchemaNamespace("");                         // import schema for the non-namespace

    DocumentBuilder builder = proc.newDocumentBuilder();
    builder.setLineNumbering(true);
    builder.setWhitespaceStrippingPolicy(WhitespaceStrippingPolicy.ALL);
    builder.setSchemaValidator(sv);
    XdmNode booksDoc = builder.build(new File("data/books.xml"));

    // find all the ITEM elements, and for each one display the TITLE child

    XPathSelector verify = xpath.compile(". instance of document-node(schema-element(BOOKLIST))").load();
    verify.setContextItem(booksDoc);
    if (((XdmAtomicValue)verify.evaluateSingle()).getBooleanValue()) {
        XPathSelector selector = xpath.compile("//schema-element(ITEM)").load();
        selector.setContextItem(booksDoc);
        QName titleName = new QName("TITLE");
        for (XdmItem item: selector) {
            XdmNode title = getChild((XdmNode)item, titleName);
            System.out.println(title.getNodeName() +
                    "(" + title.getLineNumber() + "): " +
                    title.getStringValue());
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Verification failed");
    }
}

// Helper method to get the first child of an element having a given name.
// If there is no child with the given name it returns null

private static XdmNode getChild(XdmNode parent, QName childName) {
    XdmSequenceIterator iter = parent.axisIterator(Axis.CHILD, childName);
    if (iter.hasNext()) {
        return (XdmNode)iter.next();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: XPath 1.0 includes schema aware queries. dom4j/jaxen does it as does the .NET runtime. We presently use dom4j/jaxen and it works fine but I figure we should switch to the standard Java runtime if this has been added. Thanks dave

Comment: No, XPath 1.0 does not include schema awareness - unless you are using the term to mean something quite different from the way the XPath 2.0 spec uses it.

Comment: I am using the term as dom4j/jaxen and the Microsoft .NET libraries use it. From the schema they convert nodes to the specified type both for using in comparisons and returning typed results from XPath queries.